# Migration of tensorflow python script to 2.1 version

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I need to migrate some tensorflow scripts to 2.1 version. Reading about this task, I found that one of the main differences is related to tensorflow.contrib that has been removed and replaced as described in [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0).

In my scripts, tensorflow.contrib is widely used. Also using indications in the document above, I cannot clearly understand where classes have been moved (e.g. tf.contrib.quantization)

Anyone can help me to understand how locate this library, and more in general libraries that are changed?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow migratation guide would be the place where you can start

[How to migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

Comment: The automated script does not change the import row of tensorflow.contrib.quantize.python, that still cannot be found. I would to fix ti by hand, but I cannot find out the exact position of tensorflow.contrib that has been deleted and its content has been moved away in other projects. Do you know if the content has also been modified/deleted in some parts or if it has only been moved?